# PHP Form Search JSON API

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to create a query.php with a query_result.php page for an API JSON feed. I get the return on 10 items at a time but by querying for a "year" I still don't get just that year, example YearBuilt = "1999" I still get returned vessels of all years.

QUERY.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Yacht Search</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


    <form action="http://www.yachts.theskywatergroup.com/yatco_data_feeds/datafeed_customer/query_results.php" target="_blank" method="get">

    Year Built: <input id="YearBuilt" type="text" placeholder="Year Built" name="YearBuilt" value="" size="7" maxlength="4" />
    <input name="search" type="submit" class="" value="Search Yachts" />

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

QUERY_RESULTS.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://datafeed.yatco.com/yatco.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
 <body>
<?php
$apikey = 'XXX';
$service_url = 'http://data.yatco.com/dataservice/' . $apikey . '/search?pagesize=10&pageindex=0&format=json';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);

//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://localhost');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

if ($curl_response === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
}

curl_close($curl);
$decoded = json_decode($curl_response);
if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
    die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
}

foreach ($decoded as $name => $value) {
    if ($name != 'Vessels') {
        echo $name . ' = ' . $value . '<br />';
    } else {
    foreach ($value as $entry) {
    ?>  
    <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="background-color: #a1a1a1; height: 1px;" colspan="3">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="SearchHeader" colspan="3">
                                    <span><?php Echo $entry->Boatname ?></span>&nbsp; <span><?php Echo $entry->AskingPriceFormatted?>
                                    </span>&nbsp; <span><?php Echo $entry->ApproxPriceFormatted ?></span>&nbsp; (<a href="#"
                                        class="ResultsLink" onclick="viewVessel(<?php Echo $entry->VesselID ?>);">View Details</a>)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" align="left" width="200px"><img src='<?php Echo $entry->ProfileURL ?>' alt="" title="" style="max-height: 200px;
                                        max-width: 200px;" onclick="viewVessel(<?php Echo $entry->VesselID ?>);" /></td>
                                <td valign="top" style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px;" width="200px">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="SearchLabel">LOA:</span>&nbsp; <span class="SearchData"><?php Echo $entry->LOAFeet ?>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="SearchLabel">Model Year:</span>&nbsp; <span class="SearchData"><?php Echo $entry->YearBuilt ?>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="SearchLabel">Beam:</span>&nbsp; <span class="SearchData"><?php Echo $entry->BeamFeet ?>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="SearchLabel">Draft:</span>&nbsp; <span class="SearchData"><?php Echo $entry->DraftFeet ?>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="SearchLabel">Staterooms/Sleeps:</span>&nbsp; <span class="SearchData"><?php Echo $entry->NumStaterooms ?></span>/
                                                <span class="SearchData"><?php Echo $entry->NumSleeps ?></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="5">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td valign="top" style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px;">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="SearchLabel">Builder:</span>&nbsp; <span class="SearchData"><?php Echo $entry->Builder ?>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="SearchLabel">Model:</span>&nbsp; <span class="SearchData"><?php Echo $entry->Model ?>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="SearchLabel">Type:</span>&nbsp; <span class="SearchData"><?php Echo $entry->MainCategory ?>
                                                </span>&nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="SearchLabel">Engine:</span>&nbsp; <span class="SearchData"><?php Echo $entry->EngineInfo ?>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="SearchLabel">Location:</span>&nbsp; <span class="SearchData"><?php Echo $entry->VesselLocation ?>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
    <?php
    }
    }
}

 ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where exactly in query_results.php are you using the "YearBuilt" value entered in the form?

Comment: Harry, I assumed this would return the year typed in Model Year:</span>&nbsp; <span class="SearchData"><?php Echo $entry->YearBuilt ?>

Comment: Also, here is the URL to the query http://yachts.theskywatergroup.com/yatco_data_feeds/datafeed_customer/query2.php. It does not return just the Yachts of a certain year I put in...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, I see two possible solutions for this:

1. Since you are querying an API, check if the API allows a "YearBuilt" parameter to it so that they will filter the results for you. In that case, you only change your API request and nothing else in the code changes.
2. If the above doesn't work, you can always filter yourself. In the foreach loop, add an if statement to check whether `$entry->YearBuilt` matches the year entered in the form (possibly via a comparison with `$_GET['YearBuilt']`.

**EDIT**

If you can't filter at the API level itself, then add an `if` statement in your `foreach` as follows:

```
if ($name != 'Vessels') {
    echo $name . ' = ' . $value . '<br />';
} else {
foreach ($value as $entry) {
    if($entry->YearBuilt == $_GET['YearBuilt']) {
        // all of the HTML code as it is
    }
?>
```

The `$_GET['YearBuilt']` contains the user's choice of year. Compare it with the year of the vessel as obtained from `$entry->YearBuilt` and keep only the results where the two match.

Comment: foreach ($decoded as $name => $value) {
 if ($name != 'Vessels') {
  echo $name . ' = ' . $value . '<br />';
 } else {
 foreach ($value as $entry) {
 ?>

Comment: Ok, being new to programming, I modified the if statement but still does not work...foreach ($decoded as $name => $value) {
 if ($name != 'Vessels' && $entry->YearBuilt != $_GET['YearBuilt']) {
  echo $name . ' = ' . $value . '<br />';
 } else {
 foreach ($value as $entry) {

 ?>

Comment: Hi Harry, thank you for the response. But that didn't work. http://yachts.theskywatergroup.com/yatco_data_feeds/datafeed_customer/query2.php.   I'm thinking as I'm researching this, wouldn't I want an "and" instead of "else"? It appears the first if statement would return values and thus the "else" statement would not fire. ??   Thank you for your help.

Comment: Meaning, would I use && instead of the else statement. yachts.theskywatergroup.com/yatco_data_feeds/datafeed_customer/query2.php

Answer (score 0):

$service_url = 'http://data.yatco.com/dataservice/' . $apikey . '/search?pagesize=5&pageindex=0&format=json&VesselType=motor&LOARange=30,135&YearRange=1999,2000';

try this you'll get the best results

Comment: you can remove the unwanted parameters line vesselType and LOARange just use & YearRange=1999,2000' after format=json